# Threejs and handing collisions

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I am working on a space 3D shooter game using ThreeJs.  Everything is going well except for collisions.  I have found a hand full of examples on the web via Google on how to detect if there is a collision but I can't find anything to resolve my specific issue.

Basically, if you run your ship into a planet, the ship will stop.  However after bumping into the planet if you rotate the ship and then go forward, you the cause the ship to get "sucked" into the planet!

See my demo here: http://battaglia.homedns.org/webgl/space/
 Controls: W,A,S,D to rotate the ship up, left, down, right, respectively.
 Controls: Up, Down, Left, Right to move and turn.

Here is the specific code that that have the collision detection:

```
function CollisionDetected()
{
    if (!shipSphere)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var moveDistance = 100 * delta; // 100 pixels per second
    var originPoint = shipSphere.position.clone();

    if (shipSphere)
    {
        shipSphere.position.x = ship.position.x;
        shipSphere.position.y = ship.position.y;
        shipSphere.position.z = ship.position.z;

        shipSphere.rotation.x = ship.rotation.x;
        shipSphere.rotation.y = ship.rotation.y;
        shipSphere.rotation.z = ship.rotation.z;
    }


    for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < shipSphere.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++)
    {
        var localVertex = shipSphere.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
        var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4(shipSphere.matrix);
        var directionVector = globalVertex.sub(shipSphere.position);

        var ray = new THREE.Raycaster(originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize());
        var collisionResults = ray.intersectObjects(collidableMeshList);
        if (collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length())
        {
            if (keyboard.pressed("up"))
            {
                ship.translateX(-moveDistance*2);
            }
            else if (keyboard.pressed("down"))
            {
                ship.translateX(moveDistance*2);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why do you keep track of the rotation of the sphere? Is it used to track the actual rotation of the ship too? The issue is probably that the sphere is misplaced somehow and still intersects with the collided object after collision and when you rotate and try to drive forward it registers 'keyboard.pressed("up")' and makes you move into the planet rather than from it.

Comment: The reason for the sphere is because has a fraction the number of vertices. If I use the object itself it will slow down the site to a crawl.  Also if I make the sphere visible you can see that the position is aligned with the ship.

Answer (score 0):

I assume while rotating your ship, one or more of your spheres vertices intersect with the mesh. Then, when moving, your collision code triggers, and sends your object in the wrong direction.

Try to not rotate the collision sphere, but just your ship. If the sphere keeps its orientation it should not accidentally intersect with anything while you rotate your ship.

I have done something like this with a cube as collision object, and it worked fine for me.